# software fails to write to C: with Win2003 limited user "out of disk space"

Tags: windows-server-2003, diskspace

software fails to write to profile folder stored in C:  with Win2003 limited user due  "out of disk space"

When I look with Admin rights,  there is plenty of space on C: drive

When I go with limited to user to cmd.exe and say dir c:/ ,  its 0 bytes free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is a [disc quota](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/win2003/quotas.mspx) in place.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6117811.html) explains how to setup user disk quotas in Windows SBS 2003 and Windows Server 2003.

---

*[Managing Disk Quotas in Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/win2003/quotas.mspx) has more information about setting quotas programmatically.*